# Dealing with nil current_user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm new to rails and I installed devise for user authentication. It all started innocently enough when I encountered erros while trying to do stuff like...

```
div= current_user.username
```

So of course, my first inclination was to...

```
 -if current_user
   div= current_user.username
 -else
   div= "Guest"
```

The problem is that my templates are full of this conditional logic and I want to clean up my mess, but I'm not sure how. Should I create a new Guest user and assign it to current_user? (even then, I'm not sure how to do that).

What is a good approach to dealing with nil `current_user` in Rails?

Comment: you want a guest to sign in you website, without creating a user for him self ?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, I just want to clean up my templates. Even if Guest is not an actual user I'd like current_user.username to not cause an error 500 if it doesn't exist.

Comment: you could do some thing as beef jerky suggested put a general method in the helper and user it every where in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put it in a helper?

```
def username
  if current_user
    div= current_user.username
  else
    div= "Guest"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you put slim syntax into helpers?